# i'm trying to write test apex but it gives me this error Illegal assignment from List<RL_Service_Detail__c> to Boolean

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```java
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<RL_Service_Detail__c> deleteContact(String conid) {
        if(conid != null){
            RL_Service_Detail__c delContact = [Select Id from RL_Service_Detail__c where id=:conid];
            delete delContact;
        }

        return [SELECT Id, RL_Service__c, RL_Client__r.Id, RL_Client__r.Name, RL_Category__c, RL_Sub_category__c, RL_Unit__c, RL_Billing_type__c,
                 RL_Is_Deleted__c FROM RL_Service_Detail__c ];
}
```

```java
@isTest static void testDeleteContact() {
    List<RL_Service_Detail__c> before = [SELECT Id FROM RL_Service_Detail__c];

    Test.startTest();
    Boolean result = Service.DeleteContact(before.get(0).Id);
    Test.stopTest();

    List<RL_Service_Detail__c> after = [SELECT Id FROM RL_Service_Detail__c];

    System.assert(result);
    System.assertEquals(1, before.size());
    System.assertEquals(0, after.size());
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. Your `DeleteContact()` method returns a `List<RL_Service_Detail__c>`, not a boolean. There isn't a standard way to convert between those two types. You should remove that assignment (and the related `system.assert()`), or [edit] your question to explain what you're trying to do. Like I've said on multiple occasions, you need to provide _details_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to store the returned value of the method `deleteContact` which is of type `List<RL_Service_Detail__c>` into a boolean variable named `result`.

You need to change the line

```
Boolean result = Service.DeleteContact(before.get(0).Id);
```

to

```
List<RL_Service_Detail__c> result = Service.DeleteContact(before.get(0).Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your method, you are returning List<RL_Service_Detail__c>, but in your test method, you are assigning it to Boolean.
See the below code.

```
  @isTest static void testDeleteContact() {
        List<RL_Service_Detail__c> before = [SELECT Id FROM RL_Service_Detail__c];

        Test.startTest();
        //Boolean result = Service.DeleteContact(before.get(0).Id);
        List<RL_Service_Detail__c> rlList = Service.DeleteContact(before.get(0).Id);
        Test.stopTest();

        List<RL_Service_Detail__c> after = [SELECT Id FROM RL_Service_Detail__c];

        //System.assert(result);
        System.assertEquals(1, before.size());
        System.assertEquals(0, after.size());
    }
```

Comment: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: if you are not creating test data in your test class, then you need to create that as well

Comment: sorry i didnt understand

Comment: Please see the url about test data https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data.htm